# SFML not working correctly on mac ./SFML/Window.hpp:32:10: fatal error: 'SFML/System.hpp' file not found

Tags: sfml

I downloaded and Followed the tutorial on how to install it on mac but when i open Geany and try to include everything from SFML i get an error here's 
the error and my include code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is fine, but you'll have to add SFML's `include` directory to the include directories looked through by the compiler (or more specific: the preprocessor). Unfortunately I don't know how to set this in xcode though.

Comment: @StanleyDeGraef Well, same applies there. It's not really IDE specific.